# Exporting maven project from eclipse and its deployment on tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, maven, spring-mvc

I am using [this tutorial](http://www.a2ztechguide.com/2011/11/spring-3-mvc-eclipse-project-using.html) and I did all the steps according to it. But I am stuck to the very end step that is

Build the project and deploy the war file in Tomcat. Start Tomcat and hit below URL.

URL: http://localhost:8080/springDemo-1.0/welcome.do

I done 'build project' in eclipse and I export the project as .war file to webapps of tomcat, but when I use the URL it says "HTTP Status 404" and "The requested resource (/springDemo-1.0/welcome.do) is not available." Please help

Comment: what's the war's name? Did you try `http://localhost:8080/YOUR_WAR_NAME/welcome.do`?

Comment: yes my war file name is springDemo.war and I use the same link pattern you have mention and also I try the http://localhost:8080/springDemo-1.0/welcome.do link as well, but no use.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/springDemo/welcome.do ? Note the missing version number - the name of the war (without extension) is used, assuming no other directives are set in `web.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better is to use m2e-wtp plugin for eclipse

Update site http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2eclipse-wtp/

After install update maven configuration (Maven -> Update Configuration). Now you can simple add WAR project to Tomcat instance configured in Eclipse WTP.

More about using this -> https://docs.sonatype.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/WTP+mini+howto

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try manually loading the project into Tomcat. Go to http://localhost:8080 and click on "Tomcat Manager". At the bottom, upload your WAR and hit "Deploy". You should then be able to click on the link in the table, add the "/welcome.do", and see your page.

If you are denied access to the Tomcat manager, you might have to update the tomcat-users.xml in your Tomcat's `conf` folder (for example, see below).

```
<role rolename="manager-gui" /> 
<user username="admin" password="password" roles="manager-gui" />
```

With the above, you can access the manager using admin/password.